# Elementary Set Theory Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I had this one proof as homework and I feel like I almost have it but something might be missing or the approach might not be correct.

Prove: P(A$^\complement \cap$ B$^\complement$) $\geq$ 1 - P(A) - P(B)

I started by using De Morgan's law: P(A$^\complement \cap$ B$^\complement$) = P(A $\cup$ B)$^\complement$

Now I use the definition of the complement (not gonna prove this here but it's just one line):

P(A $\cup$ B)$^\complement$  = 1 - P(A $\cup$ B)

By here I know that the union of two sets is:

**P(A $\cup$ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A $\cap$ B)** /*this is the part I'm wondering about*

Since I know from the first axiom of probability that any probability has to be $\geq$ 0 and so

P(A $\cap$ B) $\geq$ 0, the proof is done.

My question is just about the middle part. Our professor says we aren't allowed to use anything but the three axioms of probability and De Morgan's law without proving it in our exam.

How would I prove **P(A $\cup$ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A $\cap$ B)** ? Or is this just a statement that doesn't need to be proven?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ is a good formula to remember, along with its inclusion-exclusion siblings such as $$P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C)$$
A way to prove it from first principles is by observing that $B\cup A=(B\setminus A)\sqcup A$, thus $$P(A\cup B)=P(B\setminus A)+P(A)$$
And moreover $B=(B\setminus A)\cup (A\cap B)=(B\setminus A)\sqcup (A\cap B)$, from which $$P(B)=P(B\setminus A)+P(A\cap B)$$

Putting the two together $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$

Comment: We haven't covered the ⊔ sign yet, looks like it stands for disjoint union. Also the set difference has only been introduced marginally in our stats class. Any other way to go about this or is this the only way to prove it? Or is there an other way to do the entire proof with more elementary tools?

Comment: The symbol $\sqcup$ is indeed my very poor latex notation for disjoint union of sets - in its meaning of "I'm remarking that this union of sets is a disjoint union". All the courses of probability I've seen assume knowledge of elementary operations on sets as a prerequisite, and I sincerely cannot imagine a course of probability that does not assumes them as elementary.